# Custom, Draggable component too slow in ReactJS when Using onMouseMove()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, preact

I am trying to create a draggable preact component. My current implementation breaks if the cursor moves to fast. Here is the code.

```js
export { Draggable };

import { h } from "preact";
import { useState } from "preact/hooks";

const Draggable = (props: any) => {
    const [styles, setStyles] = useState({});
    const [diffPos, setDiffPos] = useState({ diffX: 0, diffY: 0 });
    const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);

    const dragStart = (e: MouseEvent): void => {
        const boundingRect =
            (e.currentTarget as HTMLElement).getBoundingClientRect();

        setDiffPos({
            diffX: e.screenX - boundingRect.left,
            diffY: e.screenY - boundingRect.top,
        });

        setIsDragging(true);
    }

    const dragging = (e: MouseEvent): void => {
        if (isDragging === true) {
            const left = e.screenX - diffPos.diffX;
            const top = e.screenY - diffPos.diffY;

            setStyles({ left: left, top: top });
        }
    }

    const dragEnd = (): void => {
        setIsDragging(false);
    }

    return (
        <div
            class="draggable"
            style={{ ...styles, position: "absolute" }}
            onMouseDown={dragStart}
            onMouseMove={dragging}
            onMouseUp={dragEnd}
        >
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I tried to fix it by creating a `mouseup` event listener but the element stops dragging if I move the mouse to fast.

Here is my attempted fix:

```js
export { Draggable };

import { h } from "preact";
import { useState } from "preact/hooks";

const Draggable = (props: any) => {
    const [styles, setStyles] = useState({});
    const [diffPos, setDiffPos] = useState({ diffX: 0, diffY: 0 });
    const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);

    const dragStart = (e: MouseEvent): void => {
        const boundingRect =
            (e.currentTarget as HTMLElement).getBoundingClientRect();

        setDiffPos({
            diffX: e.screenX - boundingRect.left,
            diffY: e.screenY - boundingRect.top,
        });

        setIsDragging(true);

        // ------------------------------------------------------------ Added an event listener
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, { once: true });
    }

    const dragging = (e: MouseEvent): void => {
        if (isDragging === true) {
            const left = e.screenX - diffPos.diffX;
            const top = e.screenY - diffPos.diffY;

            setStyles({ left: left, top: top });
        }
    }

    const dragEnd = (): void => {
        setIsDragging(false);
    }

    return (
        <div
            class="draggable"
            style={{ ...styles, position: "absolute" }}
            onMouseDown={dragStart}
            onMouseMove={dragging}
            // -------------------------------------------------------- Removed onMouseUp
        >
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What browsers have you tested?  There is wide variation in browser handling on drag events.

Comment: I have tested it in both Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Oh, `dragstart` is when any dragging occurs, triggered for every pixel/area you drag over.  You probably want `dragenter` and `dragleave`, which is when dragging enters or leaves an element, and dragstart should be `e.preventDefault();return false`.  There is a bit more to know, but if this solves your problem, I can put it into an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried to implement it using drag events but I could not get it to work. It seems drag events are for implementing drag and drop like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/radonirinamaminiaina/zfnj5rv4/). I am trying to achieve a result similar to [this](http://strml.github.io/react-draggable/example/).

Comment: You may want to try to make a reproducible example at a sandbox, like codesandbox.io.  It's easier to debug things when you have a working prototype on hand.

Comment: I had to convert the code from typescript to javascript because I could not get typescript to work in codesandbox. Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-wiles-howow?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Excellent, looking now, thanks!

Comment: Hey, CoffeeTurtle -- Drag in ReactJS is especially fun, hope my answer helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `onMouseMove()` triggers every time you move the mouse, so, if you move over 200 pixels very slowly, that's 200 iterations.  Try instead using `onDragStart` and `onDragEnd`.  [**Full working demo.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-sound-rulst?file=/src/index.js)

Ultimately, your change will be here in `render()`...

```
 return (
   <div
     class="draggable"
     style={{ ...styles, position: "absolute" }}
     onDragStart={(e) => dragStart(e)}
     onDragEnd={(e) => dragging(e)}
     draggable={true}
   >
     {props.children}
   </div>
 );
```

I use `dragEnd()`, so only two events actually fire with dragging: start and end.   MouseMove was being fired every time there was movement, which could be hundreds of times during dragging.

Also, by giving it that extra `draggable={true}` param, the browser will treat it as a naturally-draggable item (i.e., a semi-opaque version of the dragged item will visually appear at the position of the cursor, as the user drags the element around).

Finally, to speed up things just a smidge, I removed the `eventListener` you had for `dragEnd` in `dragStart()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.